# Segfault in gtk_window_new

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, gtk3

I have a simple GTK app written in C that segfaults on the line `window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL)`

Here is the code:

```c
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    GtkApplication *app = NULL;
    GtkWidget *window = NULL;
    app = gtk_application_new("com.github.Toothless204", G_APPLICATION_FLAGS_NONE);
    window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);

    gtk_application_add_window(app, GTK_WINDOW(window));
    int status = g_application_run(G_APPLICATION(app), argc, argv);

    g_object_unref(app);
    return status;
}
```

I have googled around to find an answer but didn't find anything that actually provided an answer as to what the problem could be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem: tried to create a window before the GTK+ initialization functions was called by the GtkApplication.

Before using GTK+, you need to initialize it.
https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/gtk3-General.html

```c
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    GtkWidget *window = NULL;

    gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

    window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    gtk_widget_show (window);

    g_signal_connect (window, "destroy",
        G_CALLBACK (gtk_main_quit), NULL);

    gtk_main();
    return 0;
}
```

For the same reason GtkApplication windows must be added after the GApplication 'startup' signal has been emitted.
https://wiki.gnome.org/HowDoI/GtkApplication

```c
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

static void activate (GApplication *app, gpointer user_data) {
    GtkWidget *window;

    window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    gtk_application_add_window(GTK_APPLICATION(app), GTK_WINDOW(window));
    gtk_widget_show (window);
}

int main (int argc, char **argv) {
    GtkApplication *app;
    int status;

    app = gtk_application_new ("com.github.Toothless204", G_APPLICATION_FLAGS_NONE);
    g_signal_connect (app, "activate", G_CALLBACK (activate), NULL);
    status = g_application_run (G_APPLICATION (app), argc, argv);

    g_object_unref (app);
    return status;
}
```

Comment: Oh right, I was under the impression that the constructor of GtkApplication would initialize the library similarly to how Gtk::Application works in gtkmm